# How to count mysql table avoiding duplicates in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hi guys i have been trying to find out how i can count each time a person has been entered in a database, i have duplicates in the same day so i need help with the code to just count 1 entry in a specific date eg below, i just want to count ID 56 once in the specific Date.

```
++++++++++++++++++++
+ ID  +   Date     +
++++++++++++++++++++
+ 56  + 17/03/2018 +
++++++++++++++++++++
+ 56  + 17/03/2018 +
++++++++++++++++++++
+ 76  + 17/03/2018 +
++++++++++++++++++++
+ 56  + 16/03/2018 +
++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Inform yourself about the SQL statement GROUP BY

Comment: First read [ask] and take the [tour].  Then do some research on SQL.  The key element you are looking for is a WHERE clause. [SQL Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/index.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you could use `count(distinct col_name)`  eg:

```
select id, coynt(distinct date) 
from my_table 
group by id
```

Comment: Thank you now got it was having the following code, i was counting the number of duplicates not the excluding them.  "SELECT IdNumber, COUNT(*) - COUNT (DISTINCT date) AS 'Days' FROM record GROUP BY idnumber "

Comment: @user3073665   .. you comment is  not clear to me  . .. if you need  post another question properly described  and ventually comment me  the link

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ and your query looks almost as in the answer above

Comment: I think he was specifically looking for a mysql answer.